# How to create a non animating unwind custom segue

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have a custom transition from controller A to B, it's just defined like this

```
@implementation Mycustomsegue
-(void)perform {
    [[self sourceViewController] presentViewController:[self destinationViewController] animated:NO completion:^{
    }];
}
@end
```

Now, when unwinding from B to A, it looks like a modal dismissal of controller B. How can I remove this? I don't want any animation or I want to control it.

Comment: How do you dismiss ? Have you used `animated:YES` there? In presenting it looks fine with `animated:NO`

Comment: By implementing this in controller A, then hooking up a button to it in controller B (using storyboard) `-(IBAction)unwindToTop:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
 
}`. There is no place to set Mycustomsegue with unwind segues as far as I could see.

Comment: This answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19956258/129202 helped me for now. I needed to subclass the main nav controller and add a method which eventually is called on controller A, which instantiates the Mycustomsegue to which I had to add a BOOL unwind property. Instantiate that, set the property to YES, then in the perform of the Mycustomsegue, call dismiss*** instead of present*** ... kind of long winded workaround but seems to work so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create simple action method and connect it to storyboard.

**Try below code**

```
- (IBAction)actionDismiss:(id)sender {

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

}
```

Select you segue and goto attribute inspector 

and set you custom class name in this case "**Mycustomsegue**"

[image]

Comment: So my previous solution didn't work, it just messed up other things around my app. I gave this a try, and it seems to work for now. Thanks.