# Custom UIStoryboardSegue on back button press?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I've got a custom `UIStoryboardSegue` that 'zooms' a `UIImageView`. Now I also need a custom `UIStoryboardSegue` that 'zooms out' when a user presses the back button in the `UINavigationController`. I've been trying to do this for some days now, but without success.

I've subclassed `UINavigationController` and added the code below to it:

```
- (UIStoryboardSegue *)segueForUnwindingToViewController:(UIViewController *)toViewController fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromViewController identifier:(NSString *)identifier {

    UIStoryboardSegue *theSegue;

    NSLog(@"Unwind called");

    if ([fromViewController isKindOfClass:[SetDetailViewController class]]) {
        theSegue = [ZoomOutSegue segueWithIdentifier:identifier source:fromViewController destination:toViewController performHandler:^(void){}];
    } else {
        theSegue = [super segueForUnwindingToViewController:toViewController fromViewController:fromViewController identifier:identifier];
    }

    return theSegue;
}
```

However, this isn't called. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What was your reasoning to subclassing UINavigationController ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17720995/segueforunwindingtoviewcontroller-fromviewcontroller-identifier-not-being-ca

Comment: Are you trying to unwind from a model viewController ?

Comment: No, from a pushed viewController

Comment: Then there is no need to subclass UINavigationController. So start by ditching the subclass. Secondly, did you connect the unwind segue to the actual button ?

Comment: @Tander No, because I'd like it to happen from the back button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I'm assuming you are still switching views with your zooming
2. I'm a Swiftie so my help will be in Swift

You should be able to capture these events by making your class a delegate of your navigation controller and then using the `willShowViewController` method of your navigation controller

- Add `UINavigationControllerDelegate` to your class when you define it
- Under your `viewDidLoad()` function add `self.navigationController?.delegate = self`
- Now you should be able to use a function that will run just before the navigation controller switches to a new view controller (so yes it will also run when the back button is pressed). In Swift it looks like this:

  ```
  func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {

  //if the view controller we are going to is one we want to trigger this action
  if let _ = viewController as? ViewController {
      //perform the thing you want here
  }}
  ```